# programmatically added option in DB but not visible // setHasOptions() no effect

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, custom-options, module, ce-1.9.1.0

[-- Edited below --]

I'm adding custom options programmatically when the `product_prepare_save` event is called. If it is the second custom option, everything works as expected, if it is the first, it will not appear.
*However*, it *will* appear when I add another custom option afterwards. I'm suspecting that I'm not saving the product correctly, but I can't find out why / how.

Here's the (shortened) function registered with the event observer:

```
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $request = $event->getRequest();
    $post = $request->getPost();

    $optionstoadd = array();
    if($post['newoptions']) {
        $optionstoadd = $post['newoptions'];
    }

    $currentProduct = $observer->getProduct();
    $currentProduct->setHasOptions(true);

    foreach ($optionstoadd as $optionId) {
        if($optionId == "") {
            continue;
        }
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option')->load($optionId)->getProductId());
        $option = $product->getOptionById($optionId);

        $data = array(...);

        $currentProduct->getOptionInstance()->addOption($data);
    }
```

**EDIT**: I have found out that `setHasOptions(true);` has no effect. I just cannot figure out why though. Also, the option itself is showing up in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer was really simple to be honest. I blame Magento's somewhat bad documentation though. I have no idea how new developers are supposed to understand the system when the documentation barely repeats the name of the functions and says nothing about what they do.

Coming to the point: Somewhere down the line, far below the place where `product_prepare_save` is dispatched, the product model calls the function `setHasOptions()` itself, which is rather annoying if you're not aware of it.

> `protected function _beforeSave()` in Mage_Catalog_Model_Product:

```
    /**
     * Set true, if any
     * Set false, ONLY if options have been affected by Options tab and Type instance tab
     */
    if ($hasOptions || (bool)$this->getTypeHasOptions()) {
        $this->setHasOptions(true);
        if ($hasRequiredOptions || (bool)$this->getTypeHasRequiredOptions()) {
            $this->setRequiredOptions(true);
        } elseif ($this->canAffectOptions()) {
            $this->setRequiredOptions(false);
        }
    } elseif ($this->canAffectOptions()) {
        $this->setHasOptions(false);
        $this->setRequiredOptions(false);
    }
    parent::_beforeSave();
```

## ***tl;dr***

**My solution** is to register another event (`product_save_before`) and call `setHasOptions()` there because this event is dispatched **after** the model calls `setHasOptions()` as described above.